# When flex direction is row reverse should the content be end justified?

Tags: css, flexbox

In [test 4 here](https://superflycss.github.io/utilities-layout/target/test/html/) the content is justified to the end of the `TestCanvas` box.  So the items are reversed, but they the alignment with the flex container also changes.  Is that correct?

The behavior in test 6 is similar where the column flex direction is reversed.  In that case the items are justified to the end of the column instead of the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction):

> ...
>
> row
>
> The flex container's main-axis is defined to be the same as the
>   text direction. The main-start and main-end points are the same as the
>   content direction.
>
> row-reverse
>
> Behaves the same as row but the **main-start and main-end points are permuted**.
>
> ...

So yes the items are reversed and the reference of alignment also.